# How to find files based on extension and dynamically replace text?

Tags: regex, vbscript

I'm trying to find the file in a folder which has a `.CAL` file extension and then edit the line which starts with a specific text.

Here's my code so far:

```
Option Explicit

Dim objFso, objOtF, cd,  content

Set objFso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
cd = Replace("C:\Users\username\Desktop\Replace.vbs", "Replace.vbs", "09781DK2886.cal")

Set objOtF = objFso.OpenTextFile(cd, 1)
content = objOtF.ReadAll
objOtF.Close

Set objOtF = objFso.OpenTextFile(cd, 2)
objOtF.Write Replace(content, "PARALLEL_VOLTAGE_TEST 125", "PARALLEL_VOLTAGE_TEST 180")
objOtF.Close
```

The problem I'm facing here is the file name "09781DK2886.cal" changes from system to system. Also, the content "PARALLEL_VOLTAGE_TEST 125" the numbers changes from system to system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first problem, you may iterate all the files in the target folder and check if the file path has a `.cal` extension.

For the second problem, you may use [Regular Expressions](https://www.regular-expressions.info/vbscript.html) to match any number of digits that come after your target string. The pattern should be something like this:

```
\bPARALLEL_VOLTAGE_TEST \d+\b
```

- `\b` asserts the position at a [word boundary](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) (to prevent matching partial words/numbers).
- `\d+` matches one or more digits.
- If the number will always consist of 3 digits, you can replace `\d+` with `\d{3}`.
- If the string that you're trying to match must be at the beginning of the line, you may replace the first `\b` with the [`^` anchor](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html).

**Here's a full example:**

```
Option Explicit

Dim objFso, objFolder, objFile, objOtF, cd, content

Dim targetDir
targetDir = "C:\Users\username\Desktop\"

Dim objRegExp
Set objRegExp = New RegExp
objRegExp.Pattern = "\bPARALLEL_VOLTAGE_TEST \d+\b"

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(targetDir)

For Each objFile in objFolder.Files
    If LCase(Right(objFile.Name, 4)) = ".cal" Then
        cd = objFile.Name

        Set objOtF = objFso.OpenTextFile(cd, 1)
        content = objOtF.ReadAll
        objOtF.Close

        Set objOtF = objFso.OpenTextFile(cd, 2)
        objOtF.Write objRegExp.Replace(content, "PARALLEL_VOLTAGE_TEST 180")
        objOtF.Close
    End If
Next
```